# Не работают прокси в requests (логин:пароль:ip:port)

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Здраствуйте! Пытаюсь спарсить сайт с проксями, но они не работают.
Формат прокси: логин:пароль:ip:port
Строка с прокси: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подключение в коде:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import config as c
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(c.proxies)
response = s.get(url=c.lolz_url + "market/", headers=c.hes, cookies=c.cookis)
```

Ошибка: requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lolz.guru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /market/ (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000251FD178DF0>, 'Connection to url.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

Прокси точно рабочие

Comment: А прокси то само работает по https?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor да

Comment: @АнтонФикалис можете дать сайт? не понятно почему не подключается, хочу сам попробовать

Comment: @Alexandr уже пофиксил, были нерабочие прокси

Answer (score 0):

```
https_proxy = "https://10.10.1.11:1080"
ftp_proxy   = "ftp://10.10.1.10:3128"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

Думаю это вам поможет

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]